# How do I automatically sign HTML emails with Enigmail and Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, digital-signature, enigmail

I can't sign HTML messages with Enigmail. Even though "Sign messages" is checked as the default, when I look at the source of the draft or sent messages, there is no signature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### View Source

```
From - Wed Sep 23 15:50:44 2015
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
FCC: mailbox://nobody@Local%20Folders/Sent
X-Identity-Key: id1
X-Account-Key: account19
Message-ID: <56030294.2080404@xxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 15:50:44 -0400
From: Chloe <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
X-Mozilla-Draft-Info: internal/draft; vcard=0; receipt=0; DSN=0; uuencode=0; attachmentreminder=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/31.7.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: xxxxxxxxxxxxx <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Subject: Test
X-Enigmail-Draft-Status: N1110
X-Send-Later-At: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 15:55:43 -0400
X-Send-Later-Uuid: {b3c572a3-bcd2-43d7-8fa1-338bc8bd900b}
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    Test<br>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Enigmail 1.8.2, Thunderbird 31.7.0